# Automatically Detection/Parsing of repeating elements ('row objects') in XML

Tags: xml, algorithm, parsing, xml-parsing

I'm trying to generically write an XML parser for consuming feeds of unknown schema. Basically, I'd like to make a best guess as to where the 'rows' lay within an XML document. Here are two example feeds:

feed 1, example:

```
<xml>
  <some-container-tag>
    <some-row-tag>
      <attribute-1>value</attribute-1>
      <attribute-2>value</attribute-2>
      <attribute-3>value</attribute-3>
      <attribute-4>value</attribute-4>
    </some-row-tag>
    <some-row-tag>
      <attribute-1>value</attribute-1>
      <attribute-2>value</attribute-2>
      <attribute-3>value</attribute-3>
      <attribute-4>value</attribute-4>
    </some-row-tag>
    ...
  </some-container-tag>
</xml>
```

feed 2, example:

```
<xml>
  <some-container-tag>
    <some-row-tag>
      <attribute-1>value</attribute-1>
      <attribute-2>value</attribute-2>
      <attribute-3>value</attribute-3>
      <attribute-4>value</attribute-4>
      <optional-nested-attribute-set>
         ...
      </optional-nested-attribute-set>
    </some-row-tag>
    <some-row-tag>
      <attribute-1>value</attribute-1>
      <attribute-2>value</attribute-2>
      <attribute-3>value</attribute-3>
      <attribute-4>value</attribute-4>
      <optional-nested-attribute-set>
         ...
      </optional-nested-attribute-set>
    </some-row-tag>
    ...
  </some-container-tag>
  <some-other-container-tag>
    <some-row-tag>
      <attribute-1>value</attribute-1>
      <attribute-2>value</attribute-2>
      <attribute-3>value</attribute-3>
      <attribute-4>value</attribute-4>
      <optional-nested-attribute-set>
         ...
      </optional-nested-attribute-set>
    </some-row-tag>
  </some-other-container-tag>
</xml>
```

What I've done so far is traverse the structure and map the xpath to a count, so for e.g. the first feed would be like:

```
xml => 1
xml/some-container-tag => 1
xml/some-container-tag/some-row-tag => n
xml/some-container-tag/some-row-tag/attribute-1 => n
xml/some-container-tag/some-row-tag/attribute-2 => n
xml/some-container-tag/some-row-tag/attribute-3 => n
xml/some-container-tag/some-row-tag/attribute-4 => n
```

Now the idea I had was that the 'fundamental unit' (the row level) would be the lowest level non-leaf node, though I'm having problems (solo dev'ing here) vetting that idea.

Of course feed 2 is 'much' more complicated in that there could be nested attributes (sub-array essentially) and that maybe there are two parent lists.

What's a good enough generic approach here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to convert a multi-dimensional tree structure to a two dimensional tabular structure.  Without a schema, you don't have a good way to be sure that your assumptions will be correct, but if you have to do it this way you have to come up with some assumptions.

You might approach it by depth in the hierarchy rather than count of nodes at a particular depth (there's nothing to say that all leaf nodes will be at the same depth, the problem you're running into now):

1. Depth 0 (root tag) indicates a new collection of data structures
2. Depth 1 (`some-container-tag`) indicates a new two dimensional structure
3. Depth 2 (`some-row-tag`) indicates a new row in the two dimensional structure
4. Depths 3+ indicate an entry into the row, which may itself have sub-entries. Perhaps these are represented as CSV strings, or as pointers to another array/tabular like data structure - but if you start adding that you're not really dealing with a two dimensional structure anymore.

All of this really depends on what you need to do with your data in the end and what sort of assumptions will be valid in the language you're choosing to process it in.  Either way, you're probably better going by *depth* rather than *count* to parse this out.  Also, if this really is schemaless, you may need to think of how you'll deal with attributes that show up in the XML.